# How to terminate active peering connections without atlas CLI?

Tags: amazon-vpc, atlas

When I delete mongodb project in atlas, I got this message:
"has active peering connections. All peering connections need to be terminated before the project can be deleted."

[image]

I deleted peering connection(AWS VPC). But it didn't do much. How can I resolve this problem?

[image]